# Как перенаправить tcp запрос на другой ip?

Tags: windows, tcp

Есть EXE программа, работает под windows, которая делает tcp запросы на IP-Address1.

Как можно перенаправить запрос на IP-Address2?

**UPD**

Нашёл один вариант в интернете, но боюсь это делать, не понимая что там, что бы не напортачить. Подскажите, что будет если сделать следующее?

> можно воспользоваться стандартными средствами, без дополнительных
> программ.
>
> Запускаем коммандную строку из-под администратора и выполняем
> следующее:
>
> C:\Windows\system32>netsh
>
> netsh>interface
>
> netsh interface>portproxy
>
> netsh interface portproxy>add v4tov4 listenport=12345
> connectaddress=192.168.0.2  connectport=22 listenaddress=0.0.0.0
>
> netsh interface portproxy>dump
>
> ## ===========================
>
> ## Конфигурация портов прокси
>
> ## ===========================
>
> pushd interface portproxy
>
> reset
>
> add v4tov4 listenport=12345 connectaddress=192.168.0.2 connectport=22
>
> popd
>
> ## Конец конфигурации портов прокси
>
> Тем самым получаем проброс порта 12345 на 192.168.0.2:22

Comment: Можно найти в программе этот адрес и поменять его, например.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов в скомпилированом exe файле?

Comment: Да, в стандартном случае делается на раз.

Comment: Что-то типа `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d IP-Address1 -j DNAT --to-destination IP-Address2` `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s IP-Address2 -j SNAT --to-source IP-Address1` - правда, придётся воткнуть в схему линуксовый шлюз. А как это сделать на Windows, я что-то и не представляю...

Comment: Если нет возможности изменить настройки EXE-программы, то можно попытаться сделать (образно говоря "используя   сфинктер") следующим образом. Воспользоваться утилитой ремапинга TCP-портов. Под windows такой функционал входил в состав различных прокси-серверов. Также можно найти отдельную утилиту **tcppm.exe**, которая входила в набор 3PROXY. Если нет возможности сделать на хосте с адресом **IP-Address1** ремапинг, то можно поднять на той же машине, где работает EXE-программа, дополнительный IP-адрес совпадающий с **IP-Address1**. И ремапить привязавшись к этому интерфейсу. Это дикий изврат!

Comment: Читал про варианты сказанные Akina и Daemon, но пока не разобрался. @Владимир Мартьянов какой случай считается стандартным? у меня есть EXE файл и куча DLL в комплекте.

Comment: @ArtGrek13 стандартный случай - нет пакеров и тому подобного и IP жестко зашит.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я пока не понимаю. Вы могли бы более развернуто рассказать?

Comment: Да, кстати, то что Вы предложили- **netsh interface portproxy** - это и есть форвардинг портов. Так даже лучше - можно обойтись встроенными средствами ОС.

Comment: @Daemon-5 то есть  если я выполню эту инструкцию, это должно помочь, и не навредит компу?

Comment: Ну если неправильно сконфигурировать штатными средствами - утилитой netsh, то максимум это потенциальная дыра в безопасности. Но перед внесением изменений просто сохраните текущую конфигурацию командой  dump в утилите. Да и в самой утилите вроде была команда сброса конфигурации к дефолтной. Нужно лишь внимательно изучить синтаксис и становится понятно, что и куда адресовать. Материалов по этому (даже на русском языке) в Сети достаточно.